# Replace occurrences arbitrarily in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the `replace() method` in order to highlight certain words in a sentence. The method replaces only the 1st occurrence of the target-word, by default. I would like to know how to ***perform arbitrary substitutions***. Ex: Replace the 2nd occurrence of the word in one case, in another case replace the 1st and 3rd occurrences, another the 2nd and 3rd, and so on. Below, the sentence contain 3 occurrences of the word "above":

```
var stc = 'above of the limit of reason, above of the capacity of the brain, above all.'
var wrd = 'above'; // target-word
var rpl = new RegExp ("\\b" + wrd + "\\b");
var wrd_subs = '<span class="myclass">above</span>'; // stylized word.
var ocr = 2; // occurrence(s).

stc = stc.replace(rpl, wrd_subs); // normal replacement.
```

The idea is to ***perform a 'normal' replacement if the value of the variable*** `ocr` ***is*** `false`, but if the value is 2, for example, only the 2nd occurrence should be replaced. I would like also, as I mentioned earlier, if possible, ***supply all occurrences at once***, in the same variable. Eg: given `var ocr = 2-3` (of course it might not be written like that!), replace the 2nd and 3rd occurrences, and given `var ocr = 1,3`, replace the 1st and 3rd occurrences. Preferably, the solution should use the `replace() method`, but I am open to other ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a replace callback with the `g` flag (to replace multiple occurrences) and then respond with either replacement text or original text depending upon a counter and your other state.

For determining which sequence of matches to replace, you can pass an array of counts.  So, to replace the 2nd and 3rd matches, you would pass `[1,2]` (since the matches are zero based).

See the [MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) of the replace callback for how it works.

---

Here's a demo of the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n0yejpnv/

```
var stc = 'above of the limit of reason, above of the capacity of the brain, above all.'

function replaceN(str, regex, replace, occurrencesArray) {
    var cntr = 0;
    return str.replace(regex, function(match) {
        var replacement;
        if (!occurrencesArray || occurrencesArray.indexOf(cntr) !== -1) {
            replacement = replace;
        } else {
            replacement = match;
        }
        ++cntr;
        return replacement;
    });
}

// replace only the second occurrence of "the" with "THE"
console.log(replaceN(stc, /the/g, "THE", [1]));

// replace the first and thirds occurrences of "above" with "Above"
console.log(replaceN(stc, /above/g, "ABOVE", [0,2]));
```

Comment: I really enjoyed your solution! One last thing I would like is that if the last parameter (occurrencesArray) is not provided , occurs a normal substitution, because I will be already knowing in advance whether the target word will be repeated or not within the sentence. Could add more this functionality , please?

Comment: @eden - I wasn't sure exactly what you asked for in your comment, but I changed the code so that if `occurrencesArray` is not passed, then it will replace all matches.  FYI, you must remember to use the `g` flag on your regex for this to work properly.

Comment: @eden - I don't know why you added the explicit `== false`.  It isn't needed.  As for the rest of your comment, multiline code is not legible in comments.